# Bing daily wallpaper

Tags: image, web-access

Bing has nice images that change daily. How can we download them regularly and also maybe download an archive of previous images?
There is an extensive discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639914/is-there-a-way-to-get-bings-photo-of-the-day), can we implement it in *Mathematica* elegantly and efficiently?

To recap the info from the link above, the url for the image is [http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx={index}&n={number}&mkt=en-US](http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=%7Bindex%7D&n=1&mkt=en-US),
where `index` is the number of days to go back and `number` is the number of images to retrieve starting from the `index` date.

After some experimentation, we can see that the maximum number of days you can go back `index` is 7, and the maximum number of images you can retrieve is 8. At the maximum of `index=7`, the maximum of `number=2` (we can only go back one week when `index=7`, but then we can also go one additional day back using `number=2`). Also, if `index=-1`, we can see tomorrow's picture. So we can get total of 10 pictures. If anybody knows how to get more, that would be cool.

Following this idea, if we open [this link](https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=7&n=1&mkt=en-US), for example, we get a very nicely formatted XML response for October 17th.

https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=7&n=1&mkt=en-US

Now, in the response, we can get the `<url>` tag

```
<url>
"/az/hprichbg/rb/ElkValleyVideo_EN-US7645555683_1366x768.jpg"
</url>
```

which we now have to merge with "https://www.bing.com" to get this link that contains the pictire:

https://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/ElkValleyVideo_EN-US7645555683_1366x768.jpg

In addition, there is a description of this image:

```
<copyright>
Elk River in the East Kootenays of British Columbia, Canada (© Carson Ganci/First Light/age fotostock)
</copyright>
```

It would also be good to add this text to the JPG "Title" tag so that it is visible in viewers that use it.

Comment: This feed does not work anymore because Bing has discontinued it. It is possible to see the image of the day in Feedreader but it transforms it into a Feedreader RSS feed and you have pay to subscribe to use it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use RawJSON to import the information:

```
bingJSON = Import[
    "http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=10&mkt=en-US",
    "RawJSON"
];
```

Then, create a template:

```
URLTemplate="https://bing.com/`urlBase`_`resolution`.jpg";
```

Finally, [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) the template with the given data:

```
Table[
    Import @ TemplateApply[
        URLTemplate,
        <|"urlBase" -> bingJSON["images"][[i, "urlbase"]], "resolution"->"1920x1080"|>
    ],
    {i, Length @ bingJSON["images"]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice ;) +1 Templating is neat.

Comment: Thanks! Very elegant! I wouldn't think of `RawJSON` and `TemplateApply`

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to export EXIF tag with the title? I know we can import EXIF, but can we export?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this:

```
base = "https://www.bing.com";
info = base <> "/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US";
Import[base <> Import[info, "JSON"][[1, 2, 1, 6, 2]]]
```

or similar, but more robust if they change structure of "JSON" in future.

```
base = "https://www.bing.com";
info = base <> "/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US";
Import[base <> Cases[
  Import[info, "JSON"], 
  HoldPattern["url" -> x_String] :> x, Infinity][[1]]
]
```

Comment: That's very nice, using JSON instead of XML. +1 Any idea about tagging the JPG file?

Answer (score 3):

As a first approximation, we can do the following. We read the xml file from the Web

```
xml = URLRead["https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=7&n=1&mkt=en-US"]
```

> HTTPResponse[Status: OK, Content type: text/xml;charset=utf-8]

Then, we can import it as an XML object

```
xmlobject = Import[xml, "XML"];
```

And find the element that contains the picture name

```
urlElement = Cases[xmlobject, XMLElement["url", _, _], Infinity]
```

> `{XMLElement["url", {}, {"/az/hprichbg/rb/ElkValleyVideo_EN-US7645555683_1366x768.jpg"}]}`

Parse it to get the string

```
url = First@Cases[urlElement, XMLElement["url", _, {urls_}] -> urls]
```

> `"/az/hprichbg/rb/ElkValleyVideo_EN-US7645555683_1366x768.jpg"`

Get the position in the file name that contains  resolution info

```
resolutionPos = First@
                StringPosition[url, "_" ~~ NumberString ~~ "x" ~~ NumberString ~~ ".jpg"]
```

> `{47, 59}`

Replace the part of the file name with the HD resolution

```
urlHD = StringReplacePart[url, "_1920x1080.jpg", resolutionPos]
```

> `"/az/hprichbg/rb/ElkValleyVideo_EN-US7645555683_1920x1080.jpg"`

Build a full URL

```
urlPicture = "https://bing.com" <> urlHD
```

> `"https://bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/ElkValleyVideo_EN-US7645555683_1920x1080.jpg"`

And finally, download the picture

```
URLDownload[urlPicture, "c:/temp/" <> Last@FileNameSplit[urlPicture]];
```

This is, of course, very simple, and might be improved in terms of efficiency by using an XML response that has more than one image, and downloading all 10 files at the same time. Additionally, I am not sure how to add the JPG "Title" tag.